# Log4j logrotation - split log file daily and archive after 2 days

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, centos6

I'm using log4j with my spring MCV application and i need to split log files daily but need to keep old files for 2 days and after that need to archive files. How can i achive this?
my configuration as follows,

```
    <Appenders>
    <File name="INBOUND-ERROR" fileName="${log-path}/inbound-errors.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <File name="OUTBOUND-ERROR" fileName="${log-path}/outbound-errors.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <File name="ENCRYPTIONDECRYPTION-ERROR" fileName="${log-path}/encryptiondecryption-errors.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="INBOUND-ADMIN" fileName="${log-path}/inbound-admin.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <File name="OUTBOUND-ADMIN" fileName="${log-path}/outbound-admin.log" append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
    </File>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile-Inbound-Appender"
                 fileName="${log-path}/inbound.log"
                 filePattern="${archive}/inbound.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="300 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="300000"/>
    </RollingFile>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile-Outbound-Appender"
                 fileName="${log-path}/outbound.log"
                 filePattern="${archive}/outbound.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="300 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="300000"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible with log4j-only means. What OS are you on? Maybe you can write a batch script, Powershell script or bash script which is run once a day (or at night) through cron or windows task scheduler to archive the "old" files.

Comment: @Fildor , i'm using centos

Answer (score 0):

The anwser is valid for **log4j2** (it is confusing - you put the tag for log4j2, but in the question your mentioned log4j).

The **interval** attribute of the **TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy** should do the magic. It is applied to the most specific time unit in the date pattern (see [manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#TriggeringPolicies)). So, it should be like this:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile-Inbound-Appender"
             fileName="${log-path}/inbound.log"
             filePattern="${archive}/inbound.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz">
    <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}.%M() :line%L - %m%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval=2/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="300 MB"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="300000"/>
</RollingFile>
```